# How to use Combo box in Generic Editable Tree Table Cell in jfoenix

Tags: java, combobox, tableview, jfoenix

I'm working on a project with jfoenix, I've made a table view and I want to make it editable. For one Of the Columns I need to limit the user while editing like the user can edit but just can choose from the combo box but I don't know how to do it
This a sample for editing text field base on jfoenix documentation http://www.jfoenix.com/documentation.html#TreeTableView

```
firstNameCol.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<DoctorTable, String> param) -> {
            return new GenericEditableTreeTableCell<>(
                    new TextFieldEditorBuilder());
        });
firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit((TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<DoctorTable, String> t) -> {..}
```

And when I tried to change TextFieldEditorBuilder() to ComboBoxEditor() I got this:

```
        startTimeCol.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<DoctorTable, String> param) -> {
            return new GenericEditableTreeTableCell<>(
                    new ComboBoxEditor() {
                        @Override
                        public Component getEditorComponent() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void setItem(Object anObject) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public Object getItem() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void selectAll() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {

                        }
                    });
        });
```

Which I don't know how to use it.